# Property setter not working in Python class

Tags: python, oop, properties

I am using a class (MainClass) over which I have no control. I want to base my class on MainClass but to add extra functionality. I have added an attribute (index) to my class (SuperClass), but when I try convert index to a property, the @.setter seems to be ignored. What is wrong here?

```
class MainClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'abc'

class SuperClass(object):
    def __init__(self, main, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SuperClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__main = main
        self._index = 0

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.__main, attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
        if attr == '_SuperClass__main':
            object.__setattr__(self, attr, val)
        return setattr(self.__main, attr, val)

    @property
    def index(self):
        return self._index

    @index.setter
    def index(self, value):
        self._index = value

main_object = MainClass()
super_object = SuperClass(main_object)
print('x', super_object.index, super_object.name)

super_object.index = 3
print('y', super_object.index)

super_object.index += 2
print('z', super_object.index)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just make `SuperClass` inherit from `Main`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__getattr__` is only used when the normal lookup mechanism fails.

`__setattr__`, however, is called for *all* attempts to set an attribute. This means your current definition creates an attribute named `index` on the
`MainClass` instance, rather than accessing the property's setter.

```
>>> super_object._SuperClass__main.index
2
```

Because `__setattr__` always calls `setattr(self.__main, attr, val)`, `+=` is effectively treated as `=`.

`__setattr__` has to handle three cases:

1. The attribute `_SuperClass__main` itself, for when you assign to `self.__main` in `__init__`.
2. Assignments to attributes that exist on `self.__main`
3. Assignments to attributes specific to `SuperClass`.

With that in mind, try

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
    if attr == '_SuperClass__main':
        super().__setattr__(attr, val)
    elif hasattr(self.__main, attr):
        setattr(self.__main, attr, val)
    else:
        super().__setattr__(attr, val)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `__setattr__` method you have defined is taking precedence over the `@index.setter`
Simplify the code and it should work:

```
class MainClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'abc'

class SuperClass(object):
    def __init__(self, main, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SuperClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__main = main
        self._index = 0

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__main.name

    @name.setter
    def name(self):
        return self.__main.name

    @property
    def index(self):
        return self._index

    @index.setter
    def index(self, value):
        self._index = value

main_object = MainClass()
super_object = SuperClass(main_object)
print('x', super_object.index, super_object.name)

super_object.index = 3
print('y', super_object.index)

super_object.index += 2
print('z', super_object.index)
```

Output:

```
x 0 abc
y 3
z 5
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see that that can work, but that means I have to set up properties and setters for all of the properties in MainClass. That is not trivial. Is there no way around that? I liked the setattr and getattr because it gets around that.

Comment: Not that I can think of. I haven't yet managed to make `property.setter` & `__setattr__`  work nicely together. And using properties exclusively is cleaner anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest the simpler option of just inheriting from `MainClass` instead of using composition and delegation:

```
class SuperClass(MainClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._index = 0

    @property
    def index(self):
        return self._index

    @index.setter
    def index(self, value):
        self._index = value
```

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work for me (I think). I am presented with MainClass object and to create the SuperClass object I would have to assign all of the properties (wouldn't I?). That would defeat the object